# javascript not functioning

Tags: javascript, html

Why isn't this HTML/JavaScript code working? It's an exams calculator.

```js
function calculate() {
  var f = parseFloat(document.getElementById("first").value);
  var s = ParseFloat(document.getElementById("second").value);
  var q = parseFloat(document.getElementById("quizes").value);
  var h = parseFloat(document.getElementById("homeworks").value);
  var fi = parseFloat(document.getElementById("final").value);
  alert(f / 4 + s / 4 + q / 2 + h / 2 + fi * 0.4);
}
```

```html
<p> first:<input type="number" id="first" </p>
<p> second:<input type="number" id="second" </p>
<p> quizes:<input type="number" id="quizes" </p>
<p> homeworks:<input type="number" id="homeworks" </p>
<p> final:<input type="number" id="final" </p>
<button onclick="calculate()">calculate</button>
```

Comment: please add the whole code to the question, and have a looke here: [mcve]

Comment: you don't post parts of code in comments ,

Comment: i did read the rest of the 2 comments following the main question

Answer (score 1):

I dont know whether is a copy mistake or an error in the actual code, but you have a capital P on parseFloat. follows the code

```
function calculate() {
    var f = parseFloat(document.getElementById("first").value); 
    var s = parseFloat(document.getElementById("second").value); 
    var q = parseFloat(document.getElementById("quizes").value); 
    var h = parseFloat(document.getElementById("homeworks").value);
    var fi = parseFloat(document.getElementById("final").value); 

    alert(f / 4 + s / 4 + q / 2 + h / 2 + fi * 0.4);
}
```

**EDIT:**
Your HTML also have some mistakes. The "input" tag is not closed.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>calculator</title>
</head>

<body>
    <p> first:<input type="number" id="first"></p>
    <p> second:<input type="number" id="second"> </p>
    <p> quizes:<input type="number" id="quizes"> </p>
    <p> homeworks:<input type="number" id="homeworks"> </p>
    <p> final:<input type="number" id="final"> 
    </p> <button onclick="calculate()">calculate</button>
    <script>
        function calculate() {
            var f = parseFloat(document.getElementById("first").value);
            var s = parseFloat(document.getElementById("second").value);
            var q = parseFloat(document.getElementById("quizes").value);
            var h = parseFloat(document.getElementById("homeworks").value);
            var fi = parseFloat(document.getElementById("final").value);

            alert(f / 4 + s / 4 + q / 2 + h / 2 + fi * 0.4);
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: do u mean i have to make it captital p ? i ried small & capital it didnt work

Comment: test it with the input tag properly closed.

Answer (score 0):

put parse instead of Parse

```
var s = ParseFloat (document.getElementById("second").value)
var s = parseFloat (document.getElementById("second").value)
```

Comment: In the function calculate:
var s = parseFloat (document.getElementById("second").value)

Comment: <script> function calculate() { var f = parseFloat (document.getElementById("first").value); var s = parseFloat (document.getElementById("second").value); var q = parseFloat (document.getElementById("quizes").value ); var h = parseFloat (document.getElementById("homeworks").value ); var fi = parseFloat (document.getElementById("final").value ); alert(f/4 + s/4 + q/2 + h/2 + fi*0.4); } </script>

Comment: @Shark At least format your question if you expecting it to be marked.